# How to do in vue js three search fields with computed

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

I am trying to create three search fields. with an input and two selectors. somehow I managed to work with two but with three it is not working I need help

```
 computed: {
    filterMembers: function () {
      let filtered = this.trabalinhos;

      if (this.searchText) {
        filtered = this.trabalinhos.filter(
          (m) => m.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchText) > -1
        );
      }

      if (this.searchTrabalho) {
        filtered = filtered.filter(
          (m) =>
            m.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTrabalho) ==
            this.searchTrabalho.toLowerCase() > -1
        );
      }

      if (this.select) {
        filtered = filtered.filter(
          (m) =>
            m.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.select) ==
            this.select.toLowerCase() > -1
        );
      }

      return filtered;
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
computed: {
  filterMembers() {
    return this.trabalinhos
      .filter(member => member.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchText))
      .filter(member => member.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTrabalho))
      .filter(member => member.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.select))
  }
}
```

#### OR

```js
computed: {
  filterMembers() {
    return this.trabalinhos
      .filter(member => 
        member.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchText) &&
        member.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTrabalho) &&
        member.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.select)
    )
  }
}
```